# VBA PowerPoint Select Data for map chart

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm new to VBA and trying to select the data range for a map chart in a Powerpoint presentation.  The following gives me an error and only works for charts that are not maps.

```
shpChartMap.Chart.SetSourceData Source:="='Sheet1'!$A$1:$B$703"
```

If I was to do this manually, I would have to right click, choose select data, and enter the range in the "Chart data range:" box.

Comment: which error gives you?

Comment: Run-time error:  Method 'SetSourceData' of object 'Chart' failed

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of a snippet of your sample data for the map chart?

Comment: I added a file to the question, but it's not showing up.  The sample data is about 700 rows like the following: Zip Code IP Discharges
40508 1205
40505 1042
40511 909